# Pygame, accessing next sprite in group, check colour

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm trying to make one of those games where you have a board of coloured blocks, you click on a block and it is removed along side all adjoining blocks of the same colour, not sure what they are called.

I already have my 'board' so to speak, it's created like this:

```
    colours = [red, green, blue, orange]

    block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    x_co_ord = 0
    y_co_ord = 0
    counter = 0

    score = 0

    for i in range(63):
        get_colour = random.randrange(4)
        blocker = Block(colours[get_colour], 25, 25)
        blocker.rect.x = (x_co_ord)
        blocker.rect.y = (y_co_ord)
        block_list.add(blocker)
        all_sprites_list.add(blocker)
        x_co_ord += 26
        counter += 1
        if counter == 9:
            x_co_ord = 0
            y_co_ord += 26
            counter = 0
```

Where Block(colours[get_colour], 25, 25) creates an image that is 25x25 pixels and a random colour from a list.

What I need to know is, can I, and if so how, access the block_list and find out two things: where the block is, and what colour it is.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
block_collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_list, True)
for block in block_collide:
    # Get co-ordinates
    block_co_ords = (block.rect.x, block.rect.y)
    # Get color
    print block.image.get_at((0, 0))
```

Any better solutions happily accepted.